# How to add many values to Reactive Subject?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

We have a [`s = Subject()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) object and a set of subscriptions to its values. We receive data in buckets (say by 1000 items) and currently perform: `Observable.from_(data.items).subscribe( lambda x: s.on_next(x))` to activate subscribers and pass data to them. Is there any simpler (shorter in terms of code) expression to fill `Subject` with a *set* of new  items?

Comment: That is one line of code. How much shorter do you want?

Comment: A single call (e. g. `s.push(data.items)`)